# Populate Employee manager data from SQL Server to a model to represent Org chart type data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the a typical employee manager relationship table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
(
    [EmpNum] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [PositionTitle] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [MgrEmpNum] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```

Using a CTE in SQL Server, I'm able to fetch the data for a particular manager and all employees that report to them along with the level.

I'm using a stored procedure to execute the CTE and using the same SP in Entity Framework to fetch the data.

What is the best way to populate this data into the following class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Subordinates { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int ManagerNumber { get; set; }
}
```

So the manager will be the only object and all their direct reports should be in Subordinates. Each subordinates can similarly have other employees reporting to them. Regardless of the method, I need the data in the model as explained above.

Comment: I think your model is a challenge here. The way you have this defined you will have to populate the subordinates for every subordinate of the current employee. This means you will have to recursively call your recursive logic to populate the List of Employees for each subordinate. At the very least it should be a lazy load. In the best case you could change your data to use nested sets instead of an adjacency list.

Comment: Why, @SeanLange?  He currently has a CTE that fetches "the data for a particular manager and all employees that report to them along with the level".   From there, it's an easy thing to iterate through that in C#, and build his class properties.

Comment: I suppose you are correct @TabAlleman. It just seemed a little odd to me but I don't think I read it correctly.

Comment: Writing a pseudo-code answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo-code, since I don't write C# often enough to know the syntax from memory:

```
MgrId = {the EmpNum of the Manager you want to populate the class for}

{Execute SQL command to call CTE that gets a particular manager and all subordinates with Level}

{Populate a DataTable with the results of the SQL Command}

foreach row in TheDataTable
 {
  if EmpNum = MgrId 'this is the manager
    {set the names and EmpNums of the class with the columns from this row}
  else 'this is a subordinate
    {add the EmpNum or Name (whichever you want) to the Employee <List> property of the class}
}
```

Comment: From what I understood, this code covers only one level of subordinates. What if there are multiple levels?
e.g. Manager -> Team Lead -> Senior Developer -> Junoir Developer
Then the main object Manager will have the Team lead as the subordinate, who in turn has the Snd Dev as his subordinate and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

Populate the data from the DB into:

```
List<Employee> employeeFromDb;
```

Created an object to store the top level manager:

```
var manager = query.First(h => h.Level == 0);
AddSubordinate(manager);
```

And then recursively call the following method:

```
private void AddSubordinate(Employee parentEmployee)
{
    var subs = employeeFromDb.Where(m => m.ManagerNumber == parentEmployee.EmployeeNumber).ToList();
    employeeFromDb.Remove(parentEmployee);

    if (subs.Count != 0)
        parentEmployee.Subordinates = new List<Employee>(subs);

    if (employeeFromDb.Count == 0)
        return;

    AddSubordinate(employeeFromDb.First());
}
```